# Iterator value change in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, iterator, maps

The function iterates through a map if the value is a string it adds it to the string text if it's a map it recalls the function and so on..

```
string functest(map<string, any> input) 
{
    string text;
    std::map<std::string, std::any>::iterator it;
    for (it = input.begin(); it != input.end(); it++)
    {
        
        std::string key = it->first;
        auto value = it->second;
        std::string type = value.type().name();
        std::string stringType = typeid(std::string).name();
        if (!stringType.compare(type))
        {
            text.append(any_cast<std::string>(value));
        }
        else
        {
            map<string, any> temp = any_cast<map<string, any>>(value);
            text.append(functest(temp));
        }
    }
    return text
}
std::map<std::string, std::any> map1;
std::map<std::string, std::any> map2;
std::map<std::string, std::any> map3;
map2["1"] = "test";
map3 = map2;
map1["test"] = map2;
map1["test2"] = map3;

functest(map1);
```

after the second call of functest we return to the first call. However, it(iterator) value is end instead of where it left off. how can I fix this?

Comment: This code can't possibly compile. `it` is an undeclared identifier where it's first used. `std::string value = it->second` won't compile as it's trying to assign `std::any` to `std::string`. `value.type()` won't compile as `std::string` doesn't have a member named `type`. Show a [mcve]

Comment: sorry about that I was trying to replicate my code in a simpler form and made some mistakes. fixed them now

Comment: You have elements in your map that are neither `std::string` nor `std::map<...>`. Namely, `map2["1"] = "test"` produces a `std::any` holding a `const char*`. The program throws `bad_any_cast` exception. Once this and a few other minor problems are fixed, the program [compiles, runs](https://godbolt.org/z/xfredx) and, as far as I can tell, produces expected output. I don't see any evidence that anything untoward happens with the iterator. What makes you believe so?